# ¿Cómo reducir los datos de un puntero con OpenMP en c++?

Tags: c++, hilos, collapse

Tengo el siguiente problema.
Estoy desarrollando un programita para calcular la energía liberada en un impacto.
Pero se me ha indicado que no use `reduction(+:T[:particulas])` ya que en números grandes puede producir una violación de segmento, que en realidad vendría de un desbordamiento de pila en versiones antiguas de openMP.

Entonces como haría para para poder reducir los resultados del puntero T sin usar reduction.

El codigo general es:

```
int particulas; //variable del control de argumentos
int N;
int *x;
int *y;
int *energia;
double *T;    
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:T[:particulas]) private(i)    
 for(i = 0; i < lim; i++){
        
        int x1 = i / N;
        int y1 = i % N;
        E[x1][y1]=0;
        
        for(int p=0;p<particulas;p++){
            double resEA=0.0;
            double resA=0.0;
            double parN=0;

            parN=N*N;
            resA=exp(sqrt(((x[p]-x1)*(x[p]-x1))+((y[p]-y1)*(y[p]-y1))));
            resEA=(energia[p]/(resA*parN));
            E[x1][y1]+=resEA;
            T[p]=T[p]+E[x1][y1];
        }                      
}
```

Comment: Pueees `reduction` en este contexto lo que va a hacer es autogestionar las variables temporales, para cada hilo, para el valor de T. Así pues, hacer simplemente `parallel for` va a paralelizar tu ciclo for, mucho más lento. Creo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773115/parallel-for-loop-in-openmp